# Running Multiple Versions of Passenger for Multiple Ruby-on-Rails Applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

After I install the Passenger Apache2 module, it gives me something like:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.17
PassengerRuby /home/passenger/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby
```

(Sorry, I have a user account called `passenger`. Don't be confused.)

So if I want to deploy another rails app that uses totally different version of ruby, then I believe it will give something similar with above configurations BUT with different ruby version, for example:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/passenger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17
PassengerRuby /home/passenger/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
```

Then how can I config the Apache2 (I'm NOT asking the Virtual Host part)? Because there are two versions of `LoadModule passenger_module`.  I don't think one Apache2 server can load two different versions of `passenger_module`, right?

I'm so confused.  Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Passenger supports multiple Ruby interpreters as of version 4.0.0. The `PassengerRuby` config option has been made a per-virtual host option, so you can customize your Ruby interpreter on a per-application basis.

For passenger 3 you would have to use proxies.

Answer (score 0):

For passenger 3.x :
One solution from phusion is to use mod_proxy to bind to passenger standalone : http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/
I'm not sure at 100%, but at 99%, you can't load two version of passenger module, because they will conflict espacially for the configuration variable like PassengerRoot, PassengerRuby which are limited to the server scope

Comment: My server requires me not to run the passenger standalone :-(  There are some really tricky security concerns there (SSL is set on Load Balancer, I cannot use reverse proxy on passenger: `PassengerEnabled off`, `ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000`, `ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000`).

Comment: I think SSL set on your load balancer is not a problem for proxing. Anyway try passnger 4, Phusion say now you can define a ruby version per virtual-host. I can't put an answer, I haven't try.